# How to add text in center of a rectangle Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

I am new to sketch and I really want to know there is anything like `Button`. In order to draw a button, I first draw a rectangle shape then I draw text on rectangle layer but I find it's very difficult to align text center in the rectangle.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific case it seems best if you create the button like in the video I'm sharing:
[image]

1. create a rectangle
2. create a text box with a number in it & make it as big as the rectangle. if it's 'auto', set it as 'fixed'
3. make the text centered vertically and horizontally

when you select both layers and resize, the text will always remain in the center

bonus:
make it a symbol, copy/paste it as many times as you want and use the symbol overrides to change the number. this way, when you change the style/color/font in the symbol, it'll change throughout.